# How to generate 3 names without the same name repeated

Tags: javascript, arrays, math, random

```
window.onload = start;

function start () {
  var name = ["Hans","Ole","Nils","Olav","Per","Knut","Kari","Line","Pia"]
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*8)
  var random2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*8)
  var random3 = Math.floor(Math.random()*8)
  var name2 = []
  name2.push(name[random])
  name2.push(name[random2])
  name2.push(name[random3])

  for(i=0; i<3; i++) {
  document.getElementById("par").innerHTML += name2[i] + "<br/>" ;
  }
}
```

So far with this code i can generate 3 random names from the name array. But i want the 3 names not to be repeated, and I don't know how to make that happen.

Comment: Shuffle and take 3.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this could help. I randomized the order of the array and then just pick the first three elements. This allows for zero repeats of names and generating a new answer each time the function is ran. Not sure what your HTML looks like so I just added the id "demo".

`var players = ["Hans","Ole","Nils","Olav","Per","Knut","Kari","Line","Pia"];`

```
function tournament() {
  var names = [];
  players.sort(function(a,b){return 0.5 - Math.random()});
  for (i=0; i<3; i++){
    names.push(players[i]);
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = names;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a solution that uses recursion.

The function **randomNames** gets repeated three times. Each time it gets called count gets increased and **names** is an array without the names that are already taken. It returns an array that holds the three random names.

```
function start () {
  var name = ["Hans","Ole","Nils","Olav","Per","Knut","Kari","Line","Pia"]

  function randomNames(count, names) {
    if(count >= 3) return [];
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*(names.length-1));
    // remove current name
    var name = names.splice(random, 1);
    return randomNames(++count, names).concat(name);
  }

  var random = randomNames(0, name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hash table for the chosen items and check against until all wanted items are found.

```js
window.onload = start;

function start() {
    var name = ["Hans", "Ole", "Nils", "Olav", "Per", "Knut", "Kari", "Line", "Pia"],
        hash = {},
        random;

    while (Object.keys(hash).length < 3) {
        do {
            random = Math.floor(Math.random() * name.length);
        } while (hash[random])
        hash[random] = true;
        document.getElementById("par").innerHTML += name[random] + "<br/>";
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="par"></div>
```

ES6 with [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

```js
window.onload = start;

function start() {
    var name = ["Hans", "Ole", "Nils", "Olav", "Per", "Knut", "Kari", "Line", "Pia"],
        hash = new Set,
        random;

    while (hash.size < 3) {
        do {
            random = Math.floor(Math.random() * name.length);
        } while (hash.has(random))
        hash.add(random);
        document.getElementById("par").innerHTML += name[random] + "<br/>";
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="par"></div>
```